# Why is not modeled AppUser on MigrationDbContext?

Tags: c#, abp

I'm starting to use **`Abp Framework (the new version - abp.io)`**, I'm using last `version 0.18.1`.

I understand I have two DbContext, one for the aplication and run-time model and other to create migrations, that allow me to have several run-time dbcontexts running into the same database, but there are something that I can't understand.

In the runtime DbContext the `AppUser` is modeled as:

```cs
builder.Entity<AppUser>(b =>
{
    b.ToTable("AbpUsers"); //Sharing the same table "AbpUsers" with the IdentityUser

    b.ConfigureFullAudited();
    b.ConfigureExtraProperties();
    b.ConfigureConcurrencyStamp();
    b.ConfigureAbpUser();

    //Moved customization to a method so we can share it with the SampleAppMigrationsDbContext class
    b.ConfigureCustomUserProperties();
});
```

However this entity is not modeled in MigrationDbContext, in MigrationDbContext I can find 'IdentityUser' entity modeled as:

```cs
builder.Entity<IdentityUser>(b =>
{
    b.ConfigureCustomUserProperties();
});
```

Why `AppUser` is not used in MigrationDbContext ??
Can someone explain it?

That situation make me to get errors in migrations when I try to have a navigation property to `AppUser` from other entity, for example:

```cs
public class Book : AuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public AppUser CreatorUser {get;set;}

}
```

When I try to add a new migration EfCore get me an error telling that can not modelling AppUser ...

In this issue: ([[Can't use AbpUser as navigation property] The property 'AppUser.ExtraProperties' could not be mapped](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/1517)).I can find a work arround, using a modelling way to migrations and other to normal DbContext ...
I would like to hava a better solution for this issue.

Can someone give me light with this?

Comment: Which sample are you talking about? Can you share both links?

Comment: Do you know Abp Framework? http://abp.io